# c# XML deserialize list of time string to list DateTime bject

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization, getter-setter

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this one.
Im returning a bunch of xml from an API call (which i have no control over).The data looks like this but with many more entries.

```
`<time>10:00:00</time>
 <go>true</go>
 <time>10:30:00</time>
 <go>false</go>
`
```

I can deserialize it fine into a list two lists of strings 
`List<string> time and list<string> go`

However i really need that time to be deserialized into a datetime object.
Right now i have the following working but only for a single instance but not for a list. Im having trouble with the getter and setter no doubt

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<DateTime> DoNotSerialize { get; set; }
[XmlElement("time")]
public List<string> time
{
     get { return DoNotSerialize.ToString("HH:MM:SS") }
     set { DoNotSerialize = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks dmitry. As mentioned i have no problem making it work with a single instance of string in a multitude of ways. I am having an issue with List<string> part.

Comment: @AndrewMacNaughton where is your code you parse xml?

Comment: Hey LB. The code was already in there but i made some minor modifications ot make it more readable. The code works fine when it is DateTime DoNotSerialize and String time -Its just the working with it as a list which is baffling me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<DateTime> DoNotSerialize { get; set; }
[XmlElement("time")]        
public List<string> time
{
    get { return DoNotSerialize.Select(item => item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList(); }
    set { DoNotSerialize = value.Select(item => DateTime.Parse(item)).ToList(); }
}
```

(I had a similar problem days ago, but with serialization instead of deserialization. If you're interested, check [my previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487650/xml-serialization-of-a-listdatetime-using-a-custom-datetime-format)...)