# XML Serialization of a List<DateTime> using a custom datetime format

Tags: c#, xml, list, datetime, serialization

I have some troubles with an XML Serialization. (Probably something similar to [THIS SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581109/c-sharp-xml-deserialize-list-of-time-string-to-list-datetime-bject), but regarding serialization instead of deserialization).
I need to serialize a `List<DateTime>`, using a custom DateTime format.
I'm able to do it for a single `DateTime` variable, but I can't figure out how to do it for a list.

Here is what I'm trying to do in my code.

For the simple `DateTime` variable I use this code:

```
[XmlType("Time")]
public class Time : BaseClass
{
    public Time()
    {
        base.Name = string.Empty;
        StartTimeDt = DateTime.Now;            
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime StartTimeDt
    {
        get { return DateTime.Parse(StartTime); }
        set { StartTime = value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"); }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("StartTime")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

to obtain this XML structure:

```
<Time Name="" StartTime="2014-05-05 11:00:00.000">
```

When I create a new instance of `Time` class and I serialize it, I obtain exatcly the XML structure I expect, with my `StartTime` variable serialized with the custom datetime format.

When I have a `List<DateTime>`, I try to use this kind of code:

```
[XmlType("Calendar")]
public class Calendar : BaseClass
{
    public Calendar()
    {
        base.Name = string.Empty;
        DaysDt = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<DateTime> DaysDt
    {
        get { return Days.Select(item => DateTime.Parse(item)).ToList(); }
        set { Days = value.Select(item => item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList(); }
    }

    [XmlArrayItem("Day", typeof(string))]
    public List<string> Days { get; set; }
}
```

to generate this XML output:

```
<Calendar Name="">
    <Days>
        <Day>2014-03-02</Day>
        <Day>2014-05-03</Day>
        <Day>[…]</Day>
    </Days>
</Annual>
```

But I'm doing something obviously wrong, because when I create a new instance of `Calendar` class and I try to add some datetimes

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.DaysDt = new List<DateTime>();
calendar.DaysDt.Add(DateTime.Now);
calendar.DaysDt.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));
calendar.DaysDt.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));
```

both my `DaysDt` and `Days` lists always contain 0 object, and when I go for serialization it serializes nothing...

Any noticeable error in this sample code? I'm quite sure I'm making some errors in the transition between the `List<DateTime>` and the `List<string>` with the custom format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake on the code you posted.

It is reasonable that nothing serializes. The DaysDt object is not serialized (because you set the XmlIgnore attribute) and you **never** assign any values on the Days object. I presume you may have mixed up getting/setting with adding items to a list.

When you execute:

```
calendar.DaysDt.Add(DateTime.Now);
```

The setter is **not** called!
So that leaves you with an empty Days object.

Try this code for example and see if it works:

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
List<DateTime> lst = new List<DateTime>();
lst.Add(DateTime.Now);
lst.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));
lst.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));
calendar.DaysDt = lst;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I was too keen on Xml attributes and datetime/string parsing that I didn't notice this mistake!